# Extension methods for both double and double?

Tags: c#

I am trying to write an extension method which accepts both `double` and `double?`.

```
public static class ExtensionMethod
{
    public static string ToFixedScale(this double? value)
    {
        return value.HasValue ? (Math.Truncate(value.Value * 100) / 100).ToString("0.00") : null;
    }
}
```

It works fine for `dobule?`, however it doesn't work for `double`. Is there a way I can use this extension method for both double and double?.

**EDIT : As all the user suggested to have two extension methods as double and double? are not of not same type, I am sure this might be the stupid question but is there a way where extension method accepts multiple types?**

Comment: How do you call it with a double ?

Comment: they are not the same type; you can't do it with just one method

Comment: another note, you might want to return string.Empty instead of null? if you want to always return a string?

Comment: Regarding your edit: No there is not, unless you make it an extension for object and use some ugly casting.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`Nullable<double>` and `double` are two different types. While there does exist an implicit conversion between these types, *extension methods* for one will not be found by the other's type. You will need to overload your method with a version that accepts a `double` for a parameter:

```
public static class ExtensionMethod
{
    public static string ToFixedScale(this double value)
    {
        return Math.Truncate(value * 100) / 100).ToString("0.00");
    }

    public static string ToFixedScale(this double? value)
    {
        return value.HasValue ? ToFixedScale(value.Value) : null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes i did something like this, I was just wondering if there is a way two create extension methods for multiple types.

Comment: @ManishMakkad Understood, but unfortunately no there isn't unless there is a common base type between the two.

Comment: @ManishMakkad Well yes, of course there is: `ToFixedScale<T>(Nullable<T> t)` for example works for infinite types (`T` can be any conceivable value type). But the important idea here is that the types must have some commonality you can leverage, otherwise you'd be good to go with `ToFixedScale(object o)`. What would that commonality be in the case of `Nullable<T>` and `T`? You either have one or the other and there is no common ground between the two.

Comment: Shouldn't second method be declared as `public static string? ToFixedScale(this double? value)` ?

Answer (score 4):

I would write two extension methods sharing some code:

```
public static class ExtensionMethods
{
    public static string ToFixedScale(this double? value)
    {
        return value.HasValue ? value.Value.ToFixedScale() : null;
    }
    public static string ToFixedScale(this double value)
    {
        return (Math.Truncate(value.Value * 100) / 100).ToString("0.00");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You have *two* different types: `double` and `Nullable<double>`; that's why you have to implement *two* extension methods:

```
public static class ExtensionMethod
{
    public static string ToFixedScale(this double value) {
      return (Math.Truncate(value * 100) / 100).ToString("0.00");
    }

    public static string ToFixedScale(this double? value)
    {
        return value.HasValue ? ToFixedScale(value.Value) : null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Write second method to use first one:

```
public static class ExtensionMethod
{
    public static string ToFixedScale(this double? value)
    {
        return value.HasValue ? (Math.Truncate(value.Value * 100) / 100).ToString("0.00") : null;
    }
    public static string ToFixedScale(this double value)
    {
        return ToFixedScale((double?)value);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply overload your extension method:

```
public static class ExtensionMethod
{
    public static string ToFixedScale(this double value) {
        return ToFixedScale((double?)value);
    }

    public static string ToFixedScale(this double? value)
    {
        return value.HasValue ? (Math.Truncate(value.Value * 100) / 100).ToString("0.00") : null;
    }
}
```

Your problem is that while `double` implicitly converts to `double?`, the extension method doesn't get this implicit conversion. So you have to provide your own overloads.

Answer (score 0):

Just implement it for `double`

```
public static string ToFixedScale(this double value)
{
    return (Math.Truncate(value * 100) / 100).ToString("0.00");
}
```

For `double?` you can then call it like this:

```
double? x = null;
string s = x?.ToFixedScale();
```